# Does BeautifulSoup .select() method support use of regex?

Tags: python, regex, select, beautifulsoup

Suppose I want to parse a html using BeautifulSoup and I wanted to use css selectors to find specific tags. I would "soupify" it by doing

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

If I wanted to find a tag whose "id" attribute has a value of "abc" I can do

```
soup.select('#abc')
```

If I wanted to find all "a" child tags under our current tag, we could do

```
soup.select('#abc a')
```

But now, suppose I want to find all "a" tags whose 'href' attributes has values that end in "xyz" I would want to use regex for that, I was hoping something along the lines of

```
soup.select('#abc a[href] = re.compile(r"xyz$")')
```

I can not seem to find anything that says BeautifulSoup's .select() method will support regex.

Answer (score 5):

The `soup.select()` function only supports CSS syntax; regular expressions are not part of that.

You *can* use such syntax to match attributes *ending* with text:

```
soup.select('#abc a[href$="xyz"]')
```

See the [CSS attribute selectors documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) over on MSDN.

You can always use the results of a CSS selector to continue the search:

```
for element in soup.select('#abc'):
    child_elements = element.find_all(href=re.compile('^http://example.com/\d+.html'))
```

Note that, as the [`element.select()` documentation states](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

> This is a convenience for users who know the CSS selector syntax. You can do all this stuff with the Beautiful Soup API. And if CSS selectors are all you need, you might as well use lxml directly: it’s a lot faster, and it supports more CSS selectors. **But this lets you *combine* simple CSS selectors with the Beautiful Soup API.**

*Emphasis mine*.

Comment: This is awesome. For in my example, it just for generic case. The reason I asked for regex support is because there are other patterns I wish to detect for that can happen at the beginning, the end, or in middle. Also I wish to be able to detect more than just xyz, but also for variable amount of digits.