# BeautifulSoup get text links?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have the following code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
block = soup.select('.meta-info a')
```

I need to get all links in block `.meta_info`

After I try to get all text of links from array `block`, only that have email address as text link.

I mean:

```
<a href="">Bla bla email@gmail.com</a>
```

How can I get it?

I tried as:

```
 for item in block:
            email_par = emailFromString(item.text)

            if email_par[0]:
                pass
```

But it works not stable

Comment: post some HTML so that we can better understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this link might be helpful [css select with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27070690/does-beautifulsoup-select-method-support-use-of-regex)

if you still cant figure it out try this,
make sure you have the latest version of BeautifulSoup

```
import re
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
block = soup.select('.meta-info a')

emails = block.find_all(text=re.compile('.*@.*\.com'))
```

now you can iterate over it and extract the text from each of the links

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
soup.find_all(name='a', text=re.compile(r'@'))
```